# Cannot get row data after SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a bit new to PHP as well as MySQL and I'm having an issue (I'm not even sure if this is possible) here's my issue:

I have this table here:

[image: Table]

And I use this statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(SPLIT_STRING(`date`,' ',1), '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') as month
      FROM `automation-reports`
     ) as innerTable
WHERE MONTH(month) = 5
```

Which gives me:

[image: This]

And I want to be able to get `success` from that row that contains it here:

[image: This row]

I'm not sure if this is even possible considering now data is returned for that row but like I said I'm new to MySQL so I'm not sure of the limitations.

Comment: I do not see a reason for the subquery in your FROM clause. Is your `date` column a real `DATETIME` type? If so, I see no need for any of the string manipulation either, but that might be a string in a non-mysql date format.  In any case, you could probably use `HAVING MONTH(month) = 5` to eliminate the subquery and easily include any other columns in `SELECT`.

Comment: Would you post the output from `SHOW CREATE TABLE \`automation-reports\`;` ? If that is indeed not a real DATETIME column, it would benefit you enormously to change it to one.

Comment: You shouldn't store HTML in your database. Keep your data clean. What happens when you decide to change your design or in case you'd like to use the data elsewhere?

Comment: No that is not an actual `date` column. The data on this table is received from an application and I need it to be formatted like that unfortunately. I was thinking the same thing. Ok so I get what you're saying in terms of using `HAVING` could you give me an example of what that would look like? Something like... `SELECT * FROM( SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(SPLIT_STRING(`date`,' ',1), '%m/%d/%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') as example FROM `automation-reports`) as innerTable HAVING MONTH(example) = 5

Comment: I think I understand what you are after and will post a full answer...

Comment: Could I convert that to a real `DATE` with the time in it? I could change some code for the application to follow MYSQL DateTime rules if I could get this issue ironed out by doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that your `date` column is not a [real `DATETIME` type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html), you will need to use `STR_TO_DATE()` but you can use a more complete date string format to return a full `DATETIME` object from it all at once. The [correct format string](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) is `'%m/%d/%Y %r'`, where `%r` is the 12 hour time `hh:mm:ss` followed by `AM/PM`. Using that format, you can wrap the entire output in `MONTH()` either in `SELECT` or in `WHERE`.

```
SELECT
  ID,
  reportid,
  report,
  success,
  STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y %r') AS realdate
FROM
  `automation-reports`
-- Apply MONTH() in the HAVING
HAVING MONTH(realdate) = 5
```

Alternatively instead of `HAVING` you can put the whole expression in `WHERE`

```
...
WHERE MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y %r') = 5)
```

But really, I would recommend changing that column to a proper `DATETIME`, as doing so will open up all of MySQL's date processing functions for you and allow the RDBMS to index and optimize the column. You cannot really change the column in place and have MySQL correctly parse the dates. Instead you need to add a new column, fill it, then remove the old column and rename the new (unless you want to keep both).

```
-- Add a DATETIME
ALTER TABLE `automation-reports` ADD realdate DATETIME;

-- And fill it with dates parsed from your string column
UPDATE `automation-reports` SET realdate = STR_TO_DATE(date, '%m/%d/%Y %r');

-- Drop the old column if you do not need both
ALTER TABLE `automation-reports` DROP date;

-- And rename the new one to the old name 
ALTER TABLE `automation-reports` CHANGE realdate date DATETIME;
```

In this case, you can set the display format of the date after you query it, which is the better course of action than storing the date as a string in the format you want to query it.

If you are in any position to rename this table right now, I would also recommend changing the table name from `automation-reports` to `automation_reports` because MySQL does not require the backtick-quoting for the underscore name, while you'll always be needing backticks with the hyphenated name.

Comment: It's crazy man, I know so little about this stuff but yet I can see how powerful these queries can be. I'm an OOP (C#) so branching into this stuff is kinda like riding a bicycle and riding a motorcycle. I get the basic concept, but there's a lot that I can learn. With that being said this is amazing information, more than I asked for - and VERY much needed. I'm going to be making the changes that you suggested. Thank you so much man.